# Zend Interfering with my function definitions. How do uninstall from wamp?

Tags: php, function

I've installed WAMP Server on my computer so that I can develop my website, however I have come to run my existing code which is running on my staging host just fine without any errors.

I'm getting errors such as:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare session_status() in >C:\wamp\www\uquiz\trunk\sessions\session.php on line 277

I have uncommented the line in the PHP config:

> ;zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"

But this hasn't suppressed the error.

I'm assuming that it's the ZEND Framework that may have already declared the function `session_status()`?

If I change the name of the function, the error disappears, but I don't want to be restricted.

Comment: You're mixing things up, the zend framework has nothing to do with zend engine extensions, which is what you've disabled. The zend framework is written in the language PHP, the zend engine, the zend engine extensions, and php modules are all written in C (or C++).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a built-in PHP function as of 5.4.

Rename your function or downgrade to PHP 5.3

http://us.php.net/session-status

Comment: Damn, I searched for that function name online and nothing came up.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Best way to search: http://php.net/session_status -- you can do that with any function name.